# Trigonometric Equation,

Tags: trigonometry

I was studying for my trigonometry test, a subject where I am usually very strong at, however I came across this questions and simply have no idea how to go about solving for m and n.

The question is as followed:

The diagram below shows the graph of $y = x\sin(x/3)$,
for $0<x<m$, and $0<y<n$, where $x$ is in radians and $m$ and $n$ are integers.

Find the values of;

a.) $m$ and $n$

[image]

I found that the functions hits the x-axis at $3\pi$ and has a period of $6\pi$ however then I do not know what to do.Also the diagram may not be clear but on the x axis it shows 2 point: $m-1$ and $m$, while on the y-axis it shows: $n-1$ and $n$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it hit the x axis at $3 \pi$, the last integer x assumes before that is $9$. Son $n=10$, right? Now do the same for the maximum of the function and you'll get m.

Answer (score 0):

If it hit the x axis at $3 \pi$, the last integer x assumes before that is $9$. Son $n=10$, right? Now do the same for the maximum of the function and you'll get m.

Answer (score 0):

m is the least integer greater than 3*PI
For n, find the maximum of the function, and n will be the least integer greater than that maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The first max value occurs at $x=\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$, where $y=\dfrac{3\pi}{2} \approx 4.71$. The first $x$-intercept occurs at $x=3\pi \approx 9.43$. You should be able to work out the rest.